# How to set Up Fred's ImageMagick Scripts for windows 10 and running those scripts from python

Tags: python, subprocess, imagemagick

can anyone explain to me in detail to set of environment for `Fred's ImageMagick Scripts` in `windows10 64bit` and running those scripts from python?
I have installed cywin64 with UNIX bc calculator and `ImageMagick` and added the path to system variable and downloaded the `textcleaner` script and convert to `.sh` and try to run it from python

```
import subprocess

cmd = 'textcleaner.sh -g -e stretch -f 25 -o 20 -t 30 -u -s 1 -T -p 20 abbott2.jpg out.png'

subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

and

```
import subprocess 
bashCommand = "sh textcleaner -g -e normalize -f 5 -o 10 -s 2 C:/Users/RahulNaidu/OneDrive/Desktop/SelvaImages/18420_0.png C:/Users/RahulNaidu/OneDrive/Desktop/SelvaImages/output.png"
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) 
output, error = process.communicate()
```

I am getting a new error every time so I need help in sorting out this error

Comment: It can be anything. Show error log.

Comment: log which we will receive in vs code

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the path to textcleaner and if that does not work, then add bash in front of that. The latter depends whether you have added the path to the script in your bash $PATH environment variable.

So this works for me.

```
import subprocess

cmd = 'bash ./textcleaner.sh -g -e stretch -f 25 -o 20 -t 30 -u -s 1 -T -p 20 abbott2.jpg out.png'

subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

You may get an error message about the bash "type" command not found. But that should not affect the processing of the image.

But please note that my scripts are free only for non-commercial use. Otherwise, you will need to contact me about licensing.

Please read the information and pointers for use on my home page at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php. There are links to some documents about running on Windows. Also see https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=25910

Comment: Yes i have added path and tried your code but i have received an error.                                   
" /bin/bash: ./textcleaner.sh: No such file or directory"

Comment: while running from bash cmd it is giving this error. "convert: no decode delegate for this image format `JPG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/562.
convert: no images defined `./textcleaner_1_32723.mpc' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3282."

Comment: Did you set up your system according to my Pointers for Use on my home page?  What is your ImageMagick version?

Comment: ImageMagick-7.0.10-18

Comment: It works fine for me on my Mac OSX Sierra with ImageMagick 7.0.10.18.  What do you get from running `magick -version`?